# How to replace single quotes and &apos in a file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I am trying to replace single quotes in a file and I used the command as 
sed `/s/'//g filename` and this command works fine but I have `&apos` character also in my file and which is not getting replaced. Can I use below code

```
sed "/s/'//g" -e '/s/&apos//g' filename
```

Comment: Why not try the code and see what happens? If it works, great... if it doesn't post the error here and people will be happy to help.

Comment: Try `sed "s/'//g" -e 's/&apos//g'`

Comment: You probably want to search for `&apos;` (with the semicolon)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a stray leading forward slash in your sed command:

```
sed "/s/'//g"
```

should be:

```
sed "s/'//g"
```

If you want multiple expressions, just use `-e` for both of them (here I'm assuming with Glenn Jackman that you want `&apos;` instead of just `&apos`):

```
sed -e "s/'//g" -e "s/&apos;//g" filename
```